# unsigned char in C not working as expected

Tags: c, unsigned-char

Since unsigned char represents 0 - 255 and the extended ascii code for 'à' is 133, I expected the following C code to print 133

```
unsigned char uc;

uc='à';

printf("%hhu \n",uc);
```

Instead, both clang and gcc produce the following error

```
error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
uc='à';
    ^
```

What went wrong?

By the way I copied à from a French language website and pasted the result into the assignment statement. What I suspect is the way I created à may not be valid.

Comment: Your editor is using UTF-8 encoding, not extended ASCII.

Comment: Your compiler most likely treats your source code as UTF-8 and not as ASCII. And in UTF-8 the letter "à" is represented as the two byte sequence 0xC3 0xA0 and therefore does not fit into a `char`, be it signed or unsigned.

Comment: The character à cannot be used in a C program. Try with \x85.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you have a link to normative reference?

Comment: As the others said, the editor uses UTF-8. You should keep it that way, it is the best encoding for most situations, i recommend you learn how UTF-8 works since every professional programmer should know that. Aou could use `wchar_t`, `char32_t` or `char16_t` to store this code point.

Comment: à seems to work fine.  It has the value 0x00c3a0

Comment: @YvesDaoust The C standard does not say anything about which additional characters outside of a basic set should be available or not available, there is nothing a valid C implementation supporting the à as a single byte character. `'\x85'` will probably also not work will since the terminal most likely expects UTF8 text.

Comment: In other words, you may have pasted a single-byte “à” (0xe0) into your editor, but the editor saved it as two bytes (0xc3 0xa0). Then your compiler read the source code without translating from UTF-8 to extended ASCII, so it saw `à` as two bytes and formed a multibyte character constant from them. That produces a value larger than 255, so the compiler warned you. One solution might be to change your editor settings to use extended ASCII. Another might be a command-line tool to convert UTF-8 files to some other character set, possibly `iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 MyFile`.

Comment: Or your compiler might have a switch to specify the encoding of the input files. Or you could switch to using a wide-character type. Note that if you get the program working with a character set in which “à” is a single byte, it can output that character, but your terminal might still be using UTF-8 and not recognize it.

Comment: à does not have the value 133, it has the value 224 or 0xE0 in Unicode. 133 is a control character.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: It is 133 in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ascii". Some people used this term a decade or two ago to denote several incompatible things. There is no reason to use it today.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Of course there is no such thing as “extended ascii”, since there is no such thing as “ascii.” However, there is such a thing as ASCII, and there are extensions, which people call [extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). You might not like the term since it is ambiguous because there are multiple different extensions or because it suggests some official extended version of ASCII, but that is a criticism of the term, not a proof that the things it refers to do not exist. Denying their existence is absurd.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: the C source character set comprises a-z, A-Z, 0-9, 29 special characters and white space characters. That's it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't see any reason why an implementation could not support à as part of the set of zero or more locale-specific members. As written in 5.2.1 Character sets in C11.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: “they are not portable” and “the C source character set comprises…” are different things. Characters may be in an implementation’s character set even if they are not portable, and this forms conforming C code. C was not intended or designed to be a write-once-run-everywhere language as Java was; it was intended to provide a core language that could be ported to, adapted for, and extended on many different platforms. And I see no justification for your claim that other characters are not a single byte. “à” is a single byte in code page 850 and in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is a compiler message telling you that that particular multibyte character in the source text is not one it can map to the single-byte characters in the character set it is using. It is not a message telling you the compiler does not allow any characters in its character set outside of the basic character set. Even if it were, that would just tell you that particular compiler does not support characters outside the basic character set, which in no way disproves that the C standard permits compilers to support such characters…

Comment: … The authoritative source on this is the C standard. C 2018 5.2.1 says “… Each set [ the source character set and the execution character set] is further divided into a basic character set, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or more locale-specific members (which are not members of the basic character set) called extended characters…”

Comment: …  5.2.1.2 1 says “The source character set may contain multibyte characters, used to represent members of the extended character set. The execution character set may also contain multibyte characters, which need not have the same encoding as for the source character set…”

Answer (score 3):

> Since unsigned char represents 0 - 255

This is true in most implementations, but the C standard does not require that a `char` is limited to 8 bit, it can be larger and support a larger range.

> and the extended ascii code for 'à' is 133,

There can be a C implementation where `'à'` has the value 133 (0x85) but since most implementations use Unicode, `'à'` probably uses the code point 224 (0xE0) which is most likely stored as UTF-8. Your Editor is also set to UTF-8 and therefore needs more than a single byte to represent characters outside of ASCII. In UTF-8, all ASCII characters are stored like they are in ASCII and need 1 byte, all other characters are a combination of 2-4 byte and bit 7 is set in every one of them. I suggest you learn how UTF-8 works, UTF-8 is the best way to store text most of the time, so you should only use something else when you have a good reason to do so.

> I expected the following C code to print 133

In UTF-8 the code point for à is stored as 0xC3 0xA0 which is combined to the value 0xE0. You can't store 0xC3 0xA0 in a 8 bit `char`. So clang reports an error.
You could try to store it in a `int`, `unsigned`, `wchar_t` or some other integer type that is large enough. GCC would store the value 0xC3A0 and not 0xE0, because that is the value inside the `''`. However, C supports wide characters. The type `wchar_t` which may support more characters is most likely `wchar_t` is 32 or 16 on your system. To write a wide character literal, you can use the prefix `L`. With a wide character literal, the compiler would store the correct value of 0xE0.

Change the code to:

```
#include <wchar.h>

....

wchar_t wc;
wc=L'à';
printf("%u \n",(unsigned)wc);
```

Comment: This answer is not written in a way that would explain to somebody unfamiliar with character sets and representing them via bytes.

Comment: “bit 7 is set in every one of them” contradicts “the code point for à is stored as 0x3C 0xA0”, since bit 7 is not set in 0x3C.